# converting strangely formatted date to a nicely formatted date

Tags: ios, xcode

I have looked through apples api and I am figuring out how I can convert a string representing a date and time like this:

2012-02-09 18:58:25

In to a date and time that looks like this:

September 2nd 2012 at 6.59pm.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NSDateFormatter object would be used here, I included a link to the documentation in a comment.